# Futuristic dystopia book where kids have superpowers and were fighting in a war for their countries; had multiple character point of views

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, dystopia

The book had a red cover and the synopsis said something like “what would you do if your country told you you were the key to winning the war?” The main boy character in the story had powers similar to an EMP, and another random character had the ability to run without ever getting tired. There were many different point of views from different characters, some kids from Russia’s side and some kids from US’s side. I think they were fighting in WW3, and it was the US against Russia and Russia had kids with powers too. Russia wanted Alaska back. It was set in the future.

The boy with EMP-like powers gets very weak when he uses them, and in the beginning of the story he is lying in a helicopter flying over the sea ready to knock out Russia's submarine radars so that they can hit them with torpedoes, which ends up working. He has a girlfriend as well there with him, and she doesn’t really like their military because they are just using them and they don’t care that using him for his powers is hurting him.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a perfect match, but I think this may be [Dead Zone](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20452184-dead-zone) by Robison Wells, the second book in his [Blackout series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/99055-blackout):

[image: Dead Zone]

The cover is indeed red, and the book starts:

> Zasha Litvyak flew across the northern Pacific, low enough that she could feel the salty spray as the ocean surged. This was the culmination of years of preparation; everything had led to this moment, and the work that would follow.
>
> The Russian Federation had invaded Alaska.

The children with powers are called lambdas, and both sides have them. I think the boy with the EMP power is on the Russian side not the US side.

Comment: thank you so much !!!!!! this is the book!!!!!

Comment: @AniaTorres good :-) Please will you click the tick mark to left of my answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks :-)